# scaleType showing error in android studio 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

first sorry for my bag English,I am very new to android studio 1.4,when i use scaleType it will show bellow error

here my xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_nature"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:background="#FFFFEA"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"
        android:textColor="#24B9FE"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

when i use scale type in my xml i got this error

error

```
<interface decelaration>,<paracelable declaration>,AidTokenType.import or AidTokenType.package expected,got 'centerCrop'
```

[image]

Comment: please add your code

Comment: Try this :-Goto File -> 'Invalidate Caches/Restart'  and restart studio.

Comment: thaq its working fine@SachinS

Comment: You are welcome, and  i added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-Goto File -> 'Invalidate Caches/Restart' and restart studio.